# In deepdoctection I am unable to detect the header. I am not able to detect the title here

Tags: deep-learning, ocr, object-detection, object-detection-api, detectron

[sample image of the model result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWruw.jpg)
I am using the introduction notebook of deep doctection to extract text. Here I am not able detect the Header and titles as well.

I want the header to be detected. It's not even drawing the bounding boxes. I have started with the github repo.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.